# Creating a wxWidgets GUI with multiple stages

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

There's lots of information about creating different layouts, dialogues, even custom controls. However I've not been able to find out how to create a window that has multiple seperate "stages", like an installer, or many of Visual Studio's project wizards.

I guess it could be done by keeping the information seperate from the controls and updating the information on stage changes as needed, then deleteing everything and recreating the window contents each time, but is this really the only and best way? Are there issues with the window size, layout, etc. that I will need to deal with that don't occur when everything is added in the frames constructor?

Comment: Have you looked at the wxWizard class?

Comment: While that does what the examples i listed did, im looking for somthing a little more general (would help if i had a good name for it), but I wont be useing next/previous/cancel buttons, i suppose more like a webpage with url's, only a tree rather than a graph navigation structure, and a desktop application rather than a website...

Answer (score 1):

`wxWizard` is a great class, but I would suggest it only when you have linear flow of steps/stages.

I think the best idea for you is to create non-re-sizable (just do not use `wxRESIZE_BORDER` style) frame and set of classes that create/destroy in-line layout on demand. Another option is to extend `wxWizard` class and supply more navigation functionality to it, but I have doubt you really need that.